# Can't connect to redis container with custom config file via redis-py

Tags: python, docker, redis, redis-py

I'm able to run a normal redis docker image with:

```
docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 -v /home/maryam/redis:/data -d redis redis-server
```

and then I can access the database via redis-py as I supposed to.
but I want to use a custom config file and In order to do so, I specify the path to my redis.conf and create the container like this:

```
docker run -v /home/maryam/Desktop/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf -v /home/maryam/redis:/data -p 6379:6379 --name redis -d redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

The container is built without any errors and I can see the redis.conf file inside it. Problem is when I want to do anything with the database via redis-py, I get the following error:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error while reading from socket: ('Connection closed by server.',)
```

I think source of the problem should be redis.conf file which I have edited and added these lines to it:

```
maxmemory 4gb (I also tried 4200000000 bytes)
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
maxmemory-samples 5
```

Without it, it works perfectly!
So any idea how can I overcome this?

Comment: Just excluding the obvious - you do have more than 4G RAM available, right?

Comment: @favoretti Yes, I have about 12gb RAM